# Why the for-loop does not work when I specific value from the drop down boxes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qvp4ru) is my code.

My problem is when I select "9" from the "from" drop-down box and then select "10" from the "to" drop-down box, finally, I click the "go" button, suppose the following for-loop should print "9" and "10" in console, however, there is nothing print to console.

```
for (let dateIndex=startDate;dateIndex<=endDate;dateIndex++){
  console.log(dateIndex);
}
```

However, if I select "9" from both drop-down boxes, it can print "9" in the console.
Besides that, if I select "10" from the "from" drop-down box and then select "11" from the "to" drop-down box, it can print "10" and "11" to the console.

Furthermore, if I select "9" from the "from" drop-down box and then select "11" from the "to" drop-down box, it prints nothing to the console.

Would you tell me what's going on?

Comment: You're (ab)using React as a wrapper for vanilla JS. Use React properly instead and create controlled inputs, meaning the values of the `<select>`s are reflected by state variables. Rule of thumb: if as a beginner, you're using refs, there's a 99% chance you're doing it wrong. (I'll also recommend to use your editor's autoformat or at least put some spaces in your code, `dateIndex=startDate;dateIndex<=endDate;dateIndex++` is unreadable)

Comment: Values are string and causes anomalies, cast start and end date to number while assigning them.

Comment: typecast your values in the for loop `dateIndex=Number(startDate);dateIndex<=Number(endDate)`

Comment: Here's your code, fixed: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bddhas

Comment: @ChrisG Would you tell me what is the meaning of the "+" in the set state function?
How to make the second drop-down box value change when the first drop-down box value change?

Comment: The `+` is a shortcut to turn a string into a number. As for the second question, you can expand the `onChange` arrow function accordingly.

Comment: I have copied the onChange function, however, the second drop-down box value does not change when the first drop-down box value change. I have updated the code, you can click the question link to view my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value selected in the drop-down box is a string, and needs to be converted to type Number

Comment: for (let dateIndex=Number(startDate);dateIndex<=Number(endDate);dateIndex++){
  console.log(dateIndex);
}